# Codeigniter's 'do_upload('file')' says "File not selected" while $_FILE['file'] has it

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter, upload

I've been searching a lot about that and every post has the same answer: load library, config and then ->do_upload('file'). Seems to solve everyone's problem but mine.

I'm using `ajax` with `FormData` to send my file (a pdf) and after I post it, it can be seen using `$_FILE` yet can't get it thru `->do_upload`.

#### views/home.php

```
 <body>
    <?php echo form_open_multipart('formulario/questionario');?>
    ...

 <div class="col-md-6">
    <label class="btn btn-secondary" for="input-c-civis">
       <input id="input-c-civis" type="file" style="display:none;" accept=".pdf">Selecionar contrato
    </label>
 </div>

<div class="col-md-6">
    <label class="btn btn-secondary" for="input-c-art-civis">
      <input id="input-c-art-civis" type="file" style="display:none;" accept=".pdf"> Selecionar contrato
    </label>
 </div>

 <div class="container justify-content-center">
    <button id="botao-submit" class="btn btn-primary" type="button">Send</button>
 </div>
```

#### /assets/js/script.js

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#botao-submit").click(function() {
        insertExtras();
    });
});

// This method gets the value from home.php elements.
function extraFormData() {
  var formData = new FormData();

  var contratoPDF = $("#input-c-civis").prop('files')[0];
  var artPDF = $("#input-c-art-civis").prop('files')[0];

  formData.append("contratoPDF", contratoPDF);
  formData.append("artPDF", artPDF);

  return formData;
}


function insertExtras() {
    $.ajax({
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        type: 'POST',
                url: 'index.php/formulario/questionario',
                data:  extraFormData()
            }).done(function(msg) {
                console.log(msg);
            }).fail(function(error) {
                console.error(error.responseText);
            })
}
```

#### /controllers/formulario.php

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Formulario extends CI_Controller {

function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->model('Extras_model', 'questionario');

    $this->load->helper(array(
        'form',
        'url'
    ));
}

public function index() {
    $this->load->view('home');
}

public function questionario() {

    $config['upload_path']   = './uploads/contratos/';
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'pdf';
    $config['max_size']      = 50000;

    $this->load->library('upload', $config);

    if (!$this->upload->do_upload('contratoPDF')) {
        $error = $this->upload->display_errors();
        print_r($error);
    } else {
        $data = array(
            'upload_data' => $this->upload->data()
        );
        echo $data;
    }

    var_dump($_FILES['contratoPDF']);
    var_dump($_FILES['artPDF']);

    }
}
?>
```

So after sending the files with ajax I get:
from: `$this->upload->display_errors();` : `You did not select a file to upload.`

but from `var_dump($_FILES['contratoPDF']);` and `var_dump($_FILES['artPDF']);` shows both arrays with files's informations.

Sorry for the wall of codes and misspelling, I tried to be as explicit as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `extraFormData()` as following:

```
function extraFormData() {
  var formData = new FormData();

  var contratoPDF = $("#input-c-civis")[0].files[0];
  var artPDF = $("#input-c-art-civis")[0].files[0];

  formData.append("contratoPDF", contratoPDF);
  formData.append("artPDF", artPDF);

  return formData;
}
```

Comment: sorry I took to long too answer. IT DID WORK! I had to make some changes after that due to permission on upload folder. I really do apreciate. I had tried that solution before but something were different on the php code. Result of not knowing what you're doing and trying many approachs at once. Again, **thank you**, @Star_Man. Could you explain why $_FiLE could see with .prop while do_upload couldn't?

Comment: In /system/libraries/Upload.php you can find this code line 398,  if ( ! isset($_file))
  {
   $this->set_error('upload_no_file_selected', 'debug');
   return FALSE;
  }   That means your file did not upload from client side.